# A fast way to find the number of elements in list intersection (Python)

Tags: python, optimization

Is there any faster way to calculate this value in Python:

```
len([x for x in my_list if x in other_list])
```

I tried to use sets, since the lists' elements are unique, but I noticed no difference.

```
len(set(my_list).intersection(set(other_list)))
```

I'm working with big lists, so even the slightest improvement counts. 
Thanks

Comment: These are not the same operations: the first one is the _intersection_ of the two lists, the second is the _difference_.

Comment: You're right, it was a silly mistake. The set solution would be `len(set(my_list).intersection(set(other_list)))`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simple way is to find the least length'd list... than use that with `set.intersection`..., eg:

```
a = range(100)
b = range(50)

fst, snd = (a, b) if len(a) < len(b) else (b, a)
len(set(fst).intersection(snd))
```

Comment: You look for the shorter list in order to speed up the list to set conversion?

Comment: @nicck you only need to "unique" the first list to intersect to the longer one - you only need unique values in **one** of them to allow it to operate as a `set` since `.intersection` takes any iterable... so if the first list comes down as only have two unique values (say) it's remarkably efficient if the corresponding list has millions (say)

Comment: @nicck of course, if you happen to know the uniqueness of one list over another, than prefer that, this is a naive approach, but is generally better than converting both to `set`s aprior

Answer (score 1):

I think a generator expression like so would be fast

```
sum(1 for i in my_list if i in other_list)
```

Otherwise a `set` intersection is about as fast as it will get

```
len(set(my_list).intersection(other_list))
```

Comment: Isn't the list to set conversion more time consuming than the improvement I'd get?

Comment: You'd have to time it to be certain. The conversion itself will take time, but it will make up for itself by making the `x in other_list` operation be much faster.

Answer (score 1):

From https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity, set intersection for two sets `s` and `t` has time complexity:

Average - O(min(len(s), len(t))

Worst - O(len(s) * len(t))

`len([x for x in my_list if x in other_list])` has complexity O(n^2) which is equivalent to the worst case for `set.intersection()`.

If you use `set.intersection()` you only need to convert one of the lists to a set first:

So `len(set(my_list).intersection(other_list))` should *on average* going to be faster than the nested list comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the `filter` function. Since you mentioned you're working with huge lists, `ifilter`of `itertools` module would be a good option:

```
from itertools import ifilter
my_set = set(range(100))
other_set = set(range(50))
for item in ifilter(lambda x: x in other_set, my_set):
    print item
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to sort the two lists first and then traverse them like we want to merge them, in order to find the elements in first list belonging also to second list. This way we have an `O(n logn)` algorithm.

```
def mycount(l, m):
    l.sort()
    m.sort()
    i, j, counter = 0, 0, 0
    while i < len(l) and j < len(m):
        if l[i] == m[j]:
            counter += 1
            i += 1
        elif l[i] < m[j]:
            i += 1
        else:
            j += 1
    return counter
```

From local tests it's 100 times faster than `len([x for x in a if x in b])` when working with lists of `10000` elements.

**EDIT:**

Considering that the list elements are unique, the common elements will have a frequency two in the union of the two lists. Also they will be together when we sort this union. So the following is also valid:

```
def mycount(l, m):
    s = sorted(l + m)
    return sum(s[i] == s[i + 1] for i in xrange(len(s) - 1))
```

Similarily, we can use a counter:

```
from collections import Counter
def mycount(l, m):
    c = Counter(l)
    c.update(m)
    return sum(v == 2 for v in c.itervalues())
```

Comment: You're doing two sort operations - then a repeated while with retrieving lengths :) - I stopped reading then...